# emacs 24 - image dired - mirroring files between buffers

Tags: emacs, dired

I am new to EMACS and been trying out image-dired and trying to make this feature work "Tracking of movements in thumbnail buffer and mirroring of those movements in dired buffer, and the other way around".

So it works when i move through the image-dired-thumbnail buffer (it is reflected by cursor on corresponding file in the dired buffer). But when i move through the dired buffer, the corresponding thumbnail on the image-dired-thumbnail buffer is not highlighted.

Initially i suspected "image-dired-track-movement" variable but soon dropped the idea since it is working in reflecting the changes in the thumbanil on the dired buffer.

Any pointers will be helpful!

(sorry wanted to post an image showing my problem but apparently i dont have enough reputation :P)

Comment: Hey, that would be so cool. How can we be aware when you're done ?

Comment: it would actually be very useful. i am still posting around a bit, but no one seems to know how to do this, or is not interested in answering. will definitely update it if i get the solution.